# Resize height of dynamiaclly sized div based on window size

Tags: jquery

I have a div that is acting as a mask at the top of my page. The content of the page itself is absolutely centered on the page (see css). I give the div .holder a height based on the distance the #nav div is from the top of the window using jQuery.

CSS:

```
#pagewrap 
{
    position:absolute;
    width:915px;
    margin-left:-458px;
    padding:0;
    left:50%;
    height:100%;
    margin-top:-330px;
    top:50%;
}

.holder 
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    height: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 915px;
    z-index: 10000;
}

#nav 
{
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    width:915px;
    height:224px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:url(nav-off.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    z-index:1001;
    font-family:'Cabin',sans-serif;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var t = $("#nav");
var offset = t.offset();
$(function() 
{
    $(".holder").css("height" , offset.top);
});
```

Simple enough, but if the size of the window changes I'd like to have the height updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `jQuery resize` method to detect window size change.

```
$(window).resize(reset);

function reset(){
      var t = $("#nav");
       var offset = t.offset();
         $(function() {
              $(".holder").css("height" , offset.top);     
           });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
     reset();// set on page load
});
```

Comment: Except you wouldn't need to wrap `$(".holder").css("height" , offset.top);` in a document.ready

Comment: OK. Now that I have had an opportunity to test the solution in various browsers, I'm finding that Safari and Chrome are behaving differently than Firefox. FF updates on the fly, while the other two grow the div to cover a larger area, overlapping the other elements on the page. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Put the entire script into a function, and call that function on both document.ready and [$(window).resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)